# Returning anonymous types from stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an existing database with a set of stored procedures. I am redesigning the application layer without making changes to database objects. One of the difficulties I am faced with is there are many stored procedures which are similar to each other in that they query the same tables but return different combinations of columns.

I am neither able to return partially filled entities nor I could find a way to return anonymous types from stored procedures using Entity Framework 4.1 (and SQL Server 2008 R2). This is forcing me to define too many complex types one per stored procedure although underlying table structure is the same.

My questions are :

1. Please suggest solutions for minimising number of entities / complex types which can be implemented using EF and without making changes to database objects.
2. Also, is it possible to return partially filled entities? This would enable me to reuse entities. I am not planning to use object tracking features.
3. How can we return anonymous types from stored procedures outputs? This is also good enough for me since in most cases I am going to return the data to client in JSON format

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to return anonymous types - those are typically restricted to the scope of the method they're defined inside of.

Returning partially filled types isn't possible per se - but you could do this:

- in your database layer, call the stored procedure in question; it will return a specific complex type to match its "signature"
- using something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com), you could easily copy those returned fields in the complex type into an entity of your system, thus getting a "partially filled" entity
- return that entity from your database layer to the application to be used

You won't be able to avoid having lots of complex types just for the sake of getting the return values from the stored procedures - but you'll keep those locked away inside your database layer, they won't "leak out" into your entire application.

Comment: I have been doing this where the data size is small. But incase of large datasets being returned by SP the creation of View Models or Domain objects using mapping frameworks is proving costly. Thanks for confirming that anonymous types cannot be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **System.Data.DataTable** like good old days.

Comment: this should be in comment